# What should the tag be for cable?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

So far we have [feed-line](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed-line),[transmission-line](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transmission-line), and could easily create [cable](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cable). What should be the term we use for the wires going between the radio and antenna?

Comment: I think cable is too ambiguous. The word cable has quite a lot of other uses besides, what I would otherwise consider, "feed lines".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like feed-line.

It's more than just transmission and not as vague as cable.

Comment: I second feed-line. Simple and short.

Answer (score 4):

"Feed line" is slang, "transmission line" is the proper technical term. Chapter 24 of the ARRL Antenna Handbook is titled "Transmission Lines".

Comment: Not all transmission lines are feed lines. For example, matching and phasing stubs. The (ideal) transmission line is also an element in lumped circuit analysis that may not have any specific physical manifestation.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Amber's comment on Andrew Beals' answer, I suggest:

`feed-line` as the general tag, covering any method of getting RF from point A to point B

`coaxial-cable` as a more specific tag, covering questions about the different types of coax specifically (and not coax vs ladder line), the care and feeding of coax (regular vs direct burial and that sort of question), and things like how to crimp connectors, making a balun out of coax, etc

`coaxial-connectors` as a separate tag to discuss the relative merits of PL-259 vs N vs BNC, including crimp vs solder and adapters, but specifically excluding connectors that aren't coax.

Answer (score -1):

Except that feed-line is ambiguous as heck.  Coax is a very different beastie than parallel (open wire, ladder line) feed line.

Aside from "keep your lines short, and nearby objects can affect performance", the two (three, if you want to throw in random-wire feeds) do not intersect.

Comment: Well, we could have feed-line for the generic, and also encourage coax, ladderline, etc.

Comment: It's okay for tags to be *general* - they can be clarified by other tags (e.g. `feed-line` `co-axial`). That allows for people who are interested in all kinds of feed lines to find related questions, and also for people who are interested in coax specifically to find just those which they care about.